# How can I determine the column type with PDO?

Tags: php, database, types, pdo

I need a way to determine the type of a database column (varchar/numeric/date/...) when reading from the DB with PDO.

When fetching values from the DB, PDO produces only string values, regardless of the actual type of the table column.

Is there any non driver specific way to get this information? I know that there are SQL statements that retrieve the types for any given table but i'd prefer a more generic solution.

***EDIT:***
PDOStatement::getColumnMeta() is of no use to me, because it's not supported by the PDO driver I use at the moment (Oracle).

Comment: I don't know how relevant this is to your situation (and yes, it's perl), but I understand that the [DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader](http://search.cpan.org/~rkitover/DBIx-Class-Schema-Loader-0.07000/lib/DBIx/Class/Schema/Loader.pm) supports a number of different DBMSs, but does so by having explicit support for each.

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at this method: [PDOStatement->getColumnMeta](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.getcolumnmeta.php)

Comment: Already tried that. getColumnMeta is not supported by PDO_OCI, which I have to use here ...

Answer (score 5):

This is how I did it in my WraPDO class:

```
$tomet = $sth->getColumnMeta($column_index);
$tomet['type'] = $this->_translateNativeType($tomet['native_type']);

private function _translateNativeType($orig) {
    $trans = array(
        'VAR_STRING' => 'string',
        'STRING' => 'string',
        'BLOB' => 'blob',
        'LONGLONG' => 'int',
        'LONG' => 'int',
        'SHORT' => 'int',
        'DATETIME' => 'datetime',
        'DATE' => 'date',
        'DOUBLE' => 'real',
        'TIMESTAMP' => 'timestamp'
    );
    return $trans[$orig];
}
```

$sth: [PDOStatement->getColumnMeta](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.getcolumnmeta.php)

Comment: This is not a bad idea, but the list you have is not exhaustive. For example - NEWDECIMAL is missing.

Comment: How does `native_type` compare with `driver:decl_type`?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai My answer is outdated, not reliable nor exhaustive, and was only partly useful for MySQL, 7 years ago. I'm sure there are more advanced solutions for this problem. Anyway, you should examine the value of `driver:decl_type` and if it fits better than `native_type` then you could build a similar key-value array for that. Or use [Doctrine](https://packagist.org/packages/doctrine/orm), [Propel](https://packagist.org/packages/propel/propel) etc.

Answer (score 2):

It's marked as "experimental", but the [`PDOStatement->getColumnMeta`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.getcolumnmeta.php) method looks like it will do what you want.

Comment: Yes, looks like it. But it's not supported by PDO_OCI. So it's not useful to me here.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a function a while ago which extracted table column information.  I ended up doing something like this:

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM <table> WHERE Field = ?
```

For a typical primary key, that produces this:

```
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I then parsed the output into a usable array.  However, that was pre-PHP 5.1.0.  Now you can probably use [PDOStatement->getColumnMeta](http://us.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.getcolumnmeta.php).

Comment: You could also use the information_schema db to get these informations.

Comment: Yes, that certainly seems sensible :-) There was a reason why I didn't use the information schema db at the time, but I really can't remember what it was.

Comment: information_schema is exactly what i'm trying to avoid. I want to stay as portable across multiple DBMS as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with Oracle:

```
select COLUMN_NAME,
       DATA_TYPE,
       DATA_LENGTH,
       DATA_PRECISION,
       DATA_SCALE
from user_tab_cols
where table_name = '<Table Name>'
order by column_id
```

but it isn't portable

Many SQL flavours also have

```
DESCRIBE <Table Name>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with Postgres:

```
select
    CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH,
    COLUMN_NAME,
    IS_NULLABLE,
    COLUMN_DEFAULT,
    NUMERIC_PRECISION,
    NUMERIC_SCALE,
    UDT_NAME 
from
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
where
    TABLE_NAME='table_name'
```